# VBA Pivot Table Error

Tags: excel, pivot-table, vba

I am trying to create a pivot table with VBA but am getting Runtime Error '13' Type mismatch

I have tried several different solutions to this issue, but nothing seems to work.

My data is a roster with over 80,000 rows. I want to be able to apply the VBA code to different rosters that will have different row counts. There may already be a pivot table in the workbook, so I want to create a new pivot cache to make sure that it does not interfere with the other pivot table if one exists or that it won't pull from a cache that does not exist.

After I open my workbook, my code is as follows:

```
 Sheets.Add
        ActiveSheet.Name = "Pivot Table"
        Sheets("Roster").Activate

    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create _
    (SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=ActiveSheet.UsedRange,Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14) _
    .CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="Pivot Table!R3C1", DefaultVersion:= _
    xlPivotTableVersion14
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Try `"'Pivot Table'!R3C1"` instead of `"Pivot Table!R3C1"`.  It probably doesn't like the space in the sheet name.

Comment: Actually, the missing apostrophes cause a `Runtime error '5': IInvalid procedure call or argument`.  I'm not sure now what's causing the type mismatch.  All I can think of is that it must be something to do with your UsedRange.

Comment: Thank you for the response but it is still giving me the error. Is there another solution I may be missing?